# On hold for Opinion-based, but highly voted. Shouldn't that count for something?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/81214/should-money-be-paid-as-a-motivation-to-testers-and-developers-for-detecting-and) was recently placed on hold as primarily opinion based (tl;dr the one about put devs and testers in competition with a bonus at stake). While I agree that it is an opinion question, and the response are all opinions, is it not a valid question about navigating the workplace? And shouldn't the overwhelming response to the to the question count for something? As it currently stands, the question itself has been up-voted 48 times, the accepted answer has 105 up-votes, and the top-voted answer has 129 up-votes. Clearly, it's a question and a set of responses that many users found helpful. To have it placed on hold after such obvious success seems a little wacky.

**EDIT:** Edited title to remove popularity notion.

Comment: Just because something received upvoted is no indication that people found it helpful. Rather just that they found it relatable or funny, etc.

Comment: @DoritoStyle It has been my experience that the up-vote does indeed correlate more closely with "helpful" and "good" and not just funny and relatable. If you up-vote for funny, then you're diluting the value of the site.

Comment: You have more than enough reputation to cast a reopen vote (?). Have you done so?

Comment: @enderland Now I have ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we track the positive effects of a popular question?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/612/can-we-track-the-positive-effects-of-a-popular-question)

Comment: How much popularity does it take to make something not opinion-based? I just voted to re-open. IMHO, it's far less opinion-based than many other questions here.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I am glad you said it, given you've got the most clout on this site! This question was much less opinion-oriented, as OP proposed a solution and asked for experience-based feedback about what to expect. And many of the responses that have come back have related personal experience with similar arrangements. In my opinion (oops there's that word again), this is a useful and helpful question to keep around on the board. I know the close/reopen voting mechanism is working, though, so I don't have any real complaint other than we should be less quick on our VTC for opinions.

Comment: @KentA. - I have exactly zero clout. But I also believe that we should be closing fewer questions.

Comment: *argumentum ad numeram*

Comment: Keep in mind that popularity is a meaningless concept for something that hits HNQ. HNQ surfers frequently upvote but don't downvote questions as often and virtually never downvote answers.

Comment: @Lilienthal This meta post wasn't so much about popularity as it was about being a very useful question, with multiple useful answers. I understand that "useful" is an opinion statement. But everything on The Workplace is an opinion to some degree. Fortunately, the existing system works, and the question was voted to reopen.

Comment: That's a pretty poorly chosen title then. :)

Comment: Good point. I edited the title to be more clear.

Answer (score 6):

Note too that the "hot list" has the unfortunate effect of drawing attention to and reinforcing many questions which really didn't belong here in the first place. That kind of popularity is pretty meaningless.

Answer (score 5):

No. Popularity is not directly related to quality and the goal of stack exchange is quality (specially usefulness to future visitors).

Comment: While I agree that popularity is not a proxy for quality, this particular post contained a lot of quality.

Comment: Ah, is this about the specific question or general policy?

Answer (score 4):

If it's opinion based then it's quite rightly on hold without regard for up or downvotes.

That's what the rules are for, this isn't primarily a popularity contest. I've had an answer deleted that had 32 upvotes. Yet I know full well that it was an inappropriate answer for the site although it did actually fit the guidelines and did provide a viable solution. (I advised the OP to poo his pants at work for some reason I don't recall) it was wildly popular.

Comment: I remember seeing that advice. :)